# Looping between given to financial year (fiscal years)

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to loop and display all the years present in between given 2 financial years.
 Like given years are: `2006-07` to `2010-11`, with this I want to display all years coming in between these years and those even those two years also. 
Expected Output:`2006-07, 2007-08, 2008-09, 2009-10, 2010-11`. 
I tried using `for loop` in PHP by incrementing each year but it's going very long and clumsy.

Comment: share the code that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below

```
//year to start with
$startdate = 1960;

//year to end with - this is set to current year. You can change to specific year
$enddate = date("Y");

$years = range ($startdate,$enddate);

//print years
foreach($years as $year)
{
  echo $year . "<br />";
  echo $year.' - '. (substr($year,-2)+1)."<br />";
  echo $year.' - '.  str_pad((substr($year,-2)+1), 2 , "0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."<br />";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
$startdate = 1960;

//year to end with - this is set to current year. You can change to specific year
$enddate = 1970;

$years = range($startdate, $enddate);

//print years
foreach ($years as $year) {
    if ((substr($year, -2) + 1) <= substr($enddate, -2)) {
        echo $year . ' - ' . (substr($year, -2) + 1) . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your code works fine but for years like 2000,2001  it prints 2000-1,2001-2 (instead of 2000-01,2001-02)

Comment: Yes, it should be `echo $year . ' - ' . str_pad((substr($year, -2) + 1), 2 , "0",STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br />";`. My bad :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
// Start Year
$start_year = 1960;

//End Year
$end_year = 1970;

$all_years = range($start_year, $end_year);


array_walk($all_years, function(&$year){
    $year = $year .'-'. str_pad((substr($year, -2) + 1),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
});

print_r($all_years);
```